# Cypher: How to update property if the property is an array and an aggregated count?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a node which has property `span_id`, `contact` and `count`, where `span_id` is a fixed string, but `contacts` is an array of **contact_id**, and `count` is an integer.

My question is if Cypher query can update the node by appending new elements in the array, and aggregated the `count`?

For example, I created a node as follows

```
(s:Service {span_id:"A", contacts:["A1"], count=1}
```

Later, I got an event which has **contact_id** = "B2", and `span_id` is still "A". Now the node needs to be updated as

```
(s:Service {span_id:"A", contacts:["A1", "B2"], count=2}
```

Later again, another event has **contact_id** = "C3", `span_id`= "A", so the node needs to be updated

```
(s:Service {span_id:"A", contacts:["A1", "B2", "B3"], count=3}
```

....

Does Cypher support the updating?

Comment: Storing the size of a list property as a separate property is bad practice, as it stores redundant data, forces you to add Cypher code to maintain the size whenever the list size changes, and slows down your query. You should get rid of the `count` property. One can simply use `SIZE(n.contact)` to get the current size of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an item to a list using the addition operator. And you can set a property based on the length of the list.

```
WITH ["C3"] as mynewelement
MATCH (n {span_id:'A'})
SET n.count = size(n.contacts+mynewelement)
SET n.contact = = n.contacts + mynewelement
```

Comment: Storing the size of a list property as a separate property is bad practice, as it stores redundant data, forces you to add Cypher code to maintain the size whenever the list size changes, and slows down your query. You should get rid of the `count` property. One can simply use `SIZE(n.contact)` to get the current size of the list.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but OP didn't ask about efficiency so, ya know, I just answered the question as is. ‍♂️

Comment: I see where you're coming from. I added my comment to the question itself, which is where it belongs.